# How to extract realestate listings from 3taps API?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I want to extract realestate listing from 3taps API.

https://www.3taps.com/developers-overview.html is providing listings from many categories but I want to extract only Real Estate Category.

My Development will be in Microsoft .Net So, I have a only one choice That I have [JS](https://github.com/3taps/3taps-Javascript-Client)

Can any one guide me how to implement this API ?

I have tried the following code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jasmine Test Runner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jasmine-1.0.2/jasmine.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-1.0.2/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-1.0.2/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <!-- include source files here... -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="json.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="3taps.js"></script>
    <!-- include spec files here... -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="3tapsSpec.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.TrivialReporter());
        jasmine.getEnv().execute();
        
    var items = new threeTapsClient("crcq5ztyvj6duvuzk4pbatqn").search.search({ text: 'Real Estate', category: 'Want Housing' }, function (results) { console.log(results) });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried) prior to asking here?

Comment: If you tried the sample code, what issues did you have. There is [Documentation](http://3taps.com/developers) and [Examples](https://github.com/3taps/3taps-Javascript-Client#example) available on the site. Very kindly put, you need to have a well defined question to get a good answer. :)

Comment: Pratik, I have Updated my question. If you have any idea then let me know your answer.

Comment: Ok, so when you tried the code that you have mentioned, what problem did you have? What exactly is your question? You say you want guidance implementing the api, but the api provider has already given guidance as I have linked above. If you have problems with certain parts of the documentation, then ask it accordingly. If you can't understand how to implement certain parts of the api, then mention that. Otherwise, your question is better suited for http://www.vworker.com/

Comment: hi @bPratik when i call service by URL
https://3taps.com/search?authToken=cddf86690eb8fe6887d421b3bc8f30aa&rpp=5&page=1&source=CRAIG

it returns NUll...
Why any idea ??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful, but the documentation for 3taps is here: http://docs.3taps.com/index.html

There's a "reference" and a "search" API.  The reference API is useful for selecting which categories and locations you want to pass to the "search" API.  The documentation should give you an idea how to format the url to pass to the API.